# What is the cheapest way to send ERC20 to multiple Addresses?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, gas, ethereumjs

Let's say I got 100 tokens of any ERC20, and I want to send one of each to 100 differents addresses.

What would be the cheapest in term of gas between

- 1) creating a smart contract which takes in parameters 100 addresses and perform that transaction
- 2) Making 100 individuals regulars transactions ?

Thanks

Comment: efficiently distribute massive batches of tokens and airdrops in a single click using https://multisender.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each transaction has inherent transaction costs you should typically bundle similar actions together - so you should only issue one transactions which performs the transfer of many tokens.

So your option number 1 will be a lot cheaper than option 2.

Also, if the token contract is yours (and not yet published), you can consider writing some code inside it to facilitate such functionality. For example if you need to make such transactions often you can store the addresses inside the contract or so for further usage.